# xsl 2.0 distinct-values within a for each distinct value loop

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath-2.0

i am trying to convert an xml using xsl 2.0 this is the incoming xml

```
<sprints>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>260</sprintid>
        <name>-</name>
        <startdate>05-26-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>06-09-2016</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>6</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>56</biid>
                <name>test14</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-23 13:45:21.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-23 13:45:21.0</updatedat>
                <priority>0</priority>
                <size>8</size>
                <enddate>06-09-2016</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>06-09-2016</testenddate>
        <csv>Summary,IssueType,Description,DueDate,Story Points
            test14,story,,,8
        </csv>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>262</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>06-23-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>07-07-2016</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>12</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>59</biid>
                <name>test689</name>
                <description>-</description>
                <targetdate>2017-05-23</targetdate>
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-23 13:53:21.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-23 19:12:20.0</updatedat>
                <priority>1</priority>
                <size>11</size>
                <enddate>07-07-2016</enddate>
            </item>
            <item>
                <biid>57</biid>
                <name>sdfdsf</name>
                <description>-</description>
                <targetdate>2016-05-18</targetdate>
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-23 13:51:15.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-23 19:11:33.0</updatedat>
                <priority>2</priority>
                <size>11</size>
                <enddate>07-07-2016</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>07-07-2016</testenddate>
        <csv>Summary,IssueType,Description,DueDate,Story Points
            test689,story,-,2017-05-23,11
            sdfdsf,story,-,2016-05-18,11
        </csv>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>263</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>07-07-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>07-21-2016</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>12</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>60</biid>
                <name>test09</name>
                <description>-</description>
                <targetdate>2017-05-23</targetdate>
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-23 13:54:30.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-23 19:23:22.0</updatedat>
                <priority>3</priority>
                <size>2</size>
                <enddate>07-21-2016</enddate>
            </item>
            <item>
                <biid>88</biid>
                <name>tets89</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</updatedat>
                <priority>4</priority>
                <size>100</size>
                <enddate>07-21-2016</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>07-21-2016</testenddate>
        <csv>Summary,IssueType,Description,DueDate,Story Points
            test09,story,-,2017-05-23,2
            tets89,story,,,100
        </csv>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>264</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>07-21-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>08-04-2016</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>12</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>88</biid>
                <name>tets89</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</updatedat>
                <priority>4</priority>
                <size>100</size>
                <enddate>08-04-2016</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>08-04-2016</testenddate>
        <csv>Summary,IssueType,Description,DueDate,Story Points
            tets89,story,,,100
        </csv>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>265</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>08-04-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>08-18-2016</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>12</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>88</biid>
                <name>tets89</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</updatedat>
                <priority>4</priority>
                <size>100</size>
                <enddate>08-18-2016</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>08-18-2016</testenddate>
        <csv>Summary,IssueType,Description,DueDate,Story Points
            tets89,story,,,100
        </csv>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>266</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>08-18-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>09-01-2016</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>12</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>88</biid>
                <name>tets89</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</updatedat>
                <priority>4</priority>
                <size>100</size>
                <enddate>09-01-2016</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>09-01-2016</testenddate>
        <csv>Summary,IssueType,Description,DueDate,Story Points
            tets89,story,,,100
        </csv>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>267</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>09-01-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>09-15-2016</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>12</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>88</biid>
                <name>tets89</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</updatedat>
                <priority>4</priority>
                <size>100</size>
                <enddate>09-15-2016</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>09-15-2016</testenddate>
        <csv>Summary,IssueType,Description,DueDate,Story Points
            tets89,story,,,100
        </csv>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>268</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>09-15-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>09-29-2016</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>88</biid>
                <name>tets89</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</updatedat>
                <priority>4</priority>
                <size>100</size>
                <enddate>September</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>September</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>269</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>09-29-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>10-13-2016</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>88</biid>
                <name>tets89</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</updatedat>
                <priority>4</priority>
                <size>100</size>
                <enddate>October</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>October</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>270</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>10-13-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>10-27-2016</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>88</biid>
                <name>tets89</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 13:41:06.0</updatedat>
                <priority>4</priority>
                <size>100</size>
                <enddate>October</enddate>
            </item>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>October</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>October</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>271</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>10-27-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>11-10-2016</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>November</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>November</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>272</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>11-10-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>11-24-2016</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>November</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>November</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>273</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>11-24-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>12-08-2016</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>December</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>December</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>274</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>12-08-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>12-22-2016</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>December</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>December</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>275</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>12-22-2016</startdate>
        <enddate>01-05-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>January</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>January</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>278</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>02-02-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>02-16-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q1</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q1</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>279</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>02-16-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>03-02-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q1</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q1</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>280</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>03-02-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>03-16-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q1</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q1</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>281</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>03-16-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>03-30-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q1</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q1</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>282</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>03-30-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>04-13-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q2</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q2</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>283</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>04-13-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>04-27-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q2</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q2</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>284</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>04-27-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>05-11-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q2</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q2</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>285</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>05-11-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>05-25-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q2</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q2</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>286</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>05-25-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>06-08-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q2</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q2</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>287</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>06-08-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>06-22-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q2</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q2</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>288</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>06-22-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>07-06-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q3</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q3</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>289</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>07-06-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>07-20-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q3</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q3</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>290</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>07-20-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>08-03-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q3</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q3</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>291</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>08-03-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>08-17-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q3</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q3</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>292</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>08-17-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>08-31-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>20</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q3</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q3</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <sprint>
        <sprintid>293</sprintid>
        <name />
        <startdate>08-31-2017</startdate>
        <enddate>09-14-2017</enddate>
        <weeks>2</weeks>
        <capacity>300</capacity>
        <teamid>5</teamid>
        <items>
            <item>
                <biid>90</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-26 16:53:52.0</updatedat>
                <priority>5</priority>
                <size>500</size>
                <enddate>Q3</enddate>
            </item>
            <item>
                <biid>91</biid>
                <name>testt</name>
                <description />
                <targetdate />
                <bid>5</bid>
                <createdat>2016-05-27 03:40:23.0</createdat>
                <updatedat>2016-05-27 03:40:23.0</updatedat>
                <priority>6</priority>
                <size>4</size>
                <enddate>Q3</enddate>
            </item>
        </items>
        <testenddate>Q3</testenddate>
    </sprint>
    <result>Ok</result>
</sprints>
```

i am trying to get all distinct sprint and within these distinct sprints i would like to see all distinct items which belong to the sprint. in order to do so here is my xsl

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:variable name="sprints" select="sprints/sprint" />
    <xsl:variable name="items" select="sprints/sprint/items/item" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <sprints>
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(sprints/sprint/testenddate)">
                    <sprint>
                        <enddate><xsl:value-of select="." /></enddate>
                        <items>
                    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($items/biid)">
                            <item>
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            </item>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </items>
                    </sprint>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </sprints>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is not what i had expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <sprints>
      <sprint>
         <enddate>06-09-2016</enddate>
         <items>
            <item>56</item>
            <item>59</item>
            <item>57</item>
            <item>60</item>
            <item>88</item>
            <item>90</item>
            <item>91</item>
         </items>
      </sprint>
      <sprint>
         <enddate>06-23-2016</enddate>
         <items>
            <item>56</item>
            <item>59</item>
            <item>57</item>
            <item>60</item>
            <item>88</item>
            <item>90</item>
            <item>91</item>
         </items>
      </sprint>
      <sprint>
         <enddate>07-07-2016</enddate>
         <items>
            <item>56</item>
            <item>59</item>
            <item>57</item>
            <item>60</item>
            <item>88</item>
            <item>90</item>
            <item>91</item>
         </items>
      </sprint>
      <sprint>
         <enddate>07-21-2016</enddate>
         <items>
            <item>56</item>
            <item>59</item>
            <item>57</item>
            <item>60</item>
            <item>88</item>
            <item>90</item>
            <item>91</item>
         </items>
      </sprint>
      <sprint>
         <enddate>09-15-2016</enddate>
         <items>
            <item>56</item>
            <item>59</item>
            <item>57</item>
            <item>60</item>
            <item>88</item>
            <item>90</item>
            <item>91</item>
         </items>
      </sprint>
      <sprint>
         <enddate>September</enddate>
         <items>
            <item>56</item>
            <item>59</item>
            <item>57</item>
            <item>60</item>
            <item>88</item>
            <item>90</item>
            <item>91</item>
         </items>
      </sprint>
      <sprint>
         <enddate>October</enddate>
         <items>
            <item>56</item>
            <item>59</item>
            <item>57</item>
            <item>60</item>
            <item>88</item>
            <item>90</item>
            <item>91</item>
         </items>
      </sprint>
      <sprint>
         <enddate>November</enddate>
         <items>
            <item>56</item>
            <item>59</item>
            <item>57</item>
            <item>60</item>
            <item>88</item>
            <item>90</item>
            <item>91</item>
         </items>
      </sprint>
      <sprint>
         <enddate>December</enddate>
         <items>
            <item>56</item>
            <item>59</item>
            <item>57</item>
            <item>60</item>
            <item>88</item>
            <item>90</item>
            <item>91</item>
         </items>
      </sprint>
      <sprint>
         <enddate>January</enddate>
         <items>
            <item>56</item>
            <item>59</item>
            <item>57</item>
            <item>60</item>
            <item>88</item>
            <item>90</item>
            <item>91</item>
         </items>
      </sprint>
      <sprint>
         <enddate>Q1</enddate>
         <items>
            <item>56</item>
            <item>59</item>
            <item>57</item>
            <item>60</item>
            <item>88</item>
            <item>90</item>
            <item>91</item>
         </items>
      </sprint>
      <sprint>
         <enddate>Q2</enddate>
         <items>
            <item>56</item>
            <item>59</item>
            <item>57</item>
            <item>60</item>
            <item>88</item>
            <item>90</item>
            <item>91</item>
         </items>
      </sprint>
      <sprint>
         <enddate>Q3</enddate>
         <items>
            <item>56</item>
            <item>59</item>
            <item>57</item>
            <item>60</item>
            <item>88</item>
            <item>90</item>
            <item>91</item>
         </items>
      </sprint>
   </sprints>
</root>
```

the sprint are distinct but the all the items appear in all the sprints, i want matched with the right sprint. how can i do this?

Comment: I don't have the time for a full answer right now so here's a hint: variable `$items` contains every single `sprints/sprint/items/item` node from the entire file.  Does that help? BTW, congrats on a well-written first question, those are in short supply around here :-(

Comment: @ Jim Garrison: thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:variable name="sprints" select="/sprints/sprint" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <sprints>
                <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(sprints/sprint/testenddate)">
                    <xsl:variable name="date" select="."/>
                    <sprint>
                        <enddate><xsl:value-of select="." /></enddate>
                        <items>
                            <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($sprints[testenddate/text()=$date]/items/item/biid)">
                                <item>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                </item>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </items>
                    </sprint>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </sprints>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here's the same solution written using XSLT 2.0's grouping functions, no variables needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <sprints>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="/sprints/sprint" group-by="testenddate">
                    <sprint>
                        <enddate><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></enddate>
                        <items>
                            <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(current-group()/items/item/biid)">
                                <item>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                </item>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </items>
                    </sprint>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </sprints>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, the grouping key solved my problem. never expected such quick and clear answers in such a short amount of time! gratitude

Comment: While my solution works you should probably also pay attention to @MichaelKay's answer, given that he is the author of the XSLT "bible".

Answer (score 4):

This is much easier to achieve using xsl:for-each-group rather than distinct-values, because distinct-values only gives you the distinct date values, whereas for-each-group gives you the group of sprints having each distinct date value.

So you want something like:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/sprints/sprint" group-by="enddate">
  <sprint>
    <enddate><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></enddate>
    <items>
       <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/item" group-by="biid">
           ...
       </xsl:for-each-group>
    </items>
 </sprint>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Yes, the grouping key solved my problem. never expected such quick and clear answers in such a short amount of time! gratitude